# Array.filter vs $filter('filter')

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

Which one should i use in an angular app and why?

```
array.filter(o => o.name === myName);
```

or

```
$filter('filter')(array, {name: myName}, true);
```

Answer (score 4):

The key difference is the **shortcuts or syntactic sugar** provided by the `$filter('filter')`. For example, the following syntax can be used to get the items containing the `keyword` string in any of the item's `string` properties:

```
$filter('filter')(array, 'keyword')
```

Which can not be as simple using the standard ES5 `Array.prototype.filter`.

Whereas the general idea is the same for both approaches - to return a subset of a given array as a **NEW** array.

**Update**:

[Under the hood](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filter.js#L3) angular uses the `Array.prototype.filter`:

```
function filterFilter() {
    // predicateFn is created here...

    return Array.prototype.filter.call(array, predicateFn);
}
```

So, if you don't use the shortcuts - angular simply delegates the call to the  standard `filter`.

**To answer your question**: use the one that lets you write less code. In your particular case it would be `array.filter(o => o.name === myName);`

Comment: IIRC, $filter('filter') also seem to performs LIKE check on all properties, which is a lot more powerful than equality predicate check. (and overkill for OP's case)

Comment: @kazenorin, if you pass `true` as a `comparator` parameter angular will do the strict comparison using `angular.equals`.

Answer (score 2):

While using $filter('filter') can be easier and more syntactically attractive, I can think of four good reasons to use Array.filter over $filter('filter')

**Efficiency**

While it is true that $filter('filter') uses Array.filter under the hood, it also uses other code, including deep comparisons, in addition to Array.filter. In most cases the speed difference is negligible, but in some use cases it can be substantial. When working with large data objects for example, I've found that using Array.filter makes a difference.

**Angular 2+ does not support AngularJS-style filter**

From the [angular migration guide](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#no-angular-filter-or-orderby-filters):

> The built-in AngularJS filter and orderBy filters do not exist in
>   Angular, so you need to do the filtering and sorting yourself.

If there is any possibility that you may upgrade to Angular 2 or higher in the future, then using Array.filter will save you some migration migraines. Even if you don't plan on upgrading, clearly the Angular team didn't think the AngularJS filter was worth keeping, which leads me to think it's probably better to avoid it anyway.

**Favor native code over library code**

Libraries and frameworks like AngularJS are amazing tools; But if you have to choose between using vanilla javascript or using a library, *and there isn't a good reason to use the library*, you should always use the vanilla javascript. It is more universally understood, less dependent on 3rd party code, etc. There are a plethora of online articles arguing this point.

**"$filter" inhibits type-checking in Typescript files**

This one only applies if you use (or plan to use) Typescript. At the time of writing, the @types library for angularjs defines the return type of all $filter functions as *any*, which can lead to some serious type-checking problems if you aren't careful. By contrast, Array.filter always returns the expected array type.

Comment: "_Angular 2+ does not support AngularJS-style filter... if you have to choose between using vanilla javascript or using a library, and there isn't a good reason to use the library, you should always use the vanilla javascript._" **100% this**. One tightly couples your business logic to AngularJS. The other is vanilla JavaScript and allows the same code to be [maximally] future-proof.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `Array.filter` and then assign the result. When you use `$filter`, it is re-applied at the end of every **$digest** cycle for all the bindings and that is performance intensive to watch for the values and update the results after every **$digest** cycle. Instead you should filter your result and assign it to your scope variable explicitly

Comment: which means in turn when i assign the result of array.filter somewhere and then modify my array, the reference to the filtered array wont be updated?

Comment: Yes. Its a bit mpre boilerplate to use `array.filter` but better performance. You need to decide between the tradeoff of `performance` vs `code conciseness`

Comment: Wrong, a `$filter` does not create a watch.

Comment: @Dieterg Updated the wordings. What I actually meant was that it is re-applied after every `$digest` cycle

Comment: Wrong, filters are not applied after every `$digest` cycle (unless you have the `$stateful` flag enabled. This also only applies for using filters in your `HTML` template. This does not occur if you use `$filter` in your `controller` (unless you're in a `$watch` ofcrouse). But to be clear, I agree that it's better to use `Array.filter` in this case.