# AngularJS Custom Filter in ng-repeat Table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I can filter values in table (especific column) with this custom filter. Data come from an array of a multiple select input

Complete Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/d1sLj05t/1/

```
myApp.filter('filterMultiple',['$filter',function ($filter) {
    return function (items, keyObj) {
        var filterObj = {
            data:items,
            filteredData:[],
            applyFilter : function(obj,key){
                var fData = [];
                if(this.filteredData.length == 0)
                    this.filteredData = this.data;
                if(obj){
                    var fObj = {};
                    if(angular.isString(obj)){
                        fObj[key] = obj;
                        fData = fData.concat($filter('filter')(this.filteredData,fObj));
                    }else if(angular.isArray(obj)){
                        if(obj.length > 0){ 
                            for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
                                if(angular.isString(obj[i])){
                                    fObj[key] = obj[i];
                                    fData = fData.concat($filter('filter')(this.filteredData,fObj));    
                                }
                            }           
                        }                                       
                    }                                   
                    if(fData.length > 0){
                        this.filteredData = fData;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        if(keyObj){
            angular.forEach(keyObj,function(obj,key){
                filterObj.applyFilter(obj,key);
            });         
        }               
        return filterObj.filteredData;
    } 
}]);
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat="emp in empList | filterMultiple:{dept:selected}">
```

Perfect when values exists like "sales" or "account", but when the value not exist in the table, return all data (when i choose "not" or combinate "not" and "sales"). I expected an empty result o just the selected values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can accomplish what you want with a much simpler filter. You might want to try something like this instead:

```js
myApp.filter('filterMultiple',['$filter',function ($filter) {
    return function (items, keyObj) {
        //If the value isn't defined, don't filter at all.
        if (keyObj.value == undefined) {
            return items;
        }
        //Use javascript's native Array.filter() to get only the items that match.
        return items.filter(function(item) {
            //Keep any items whose specified attribute includes the selected value
            return item[keyObj.column].includes(keyObj.value);
        })
    }
}]);
```

And a slight change in your HTML:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="emp in empList | filterMultiple:{column:'dept', value:selected}">
```

I'm not sure what you mean by " combinate 'not' and 'sales' ", but I think this will get you moving in the right direction.

Here are some related links, in case you're not familiar with some of the things I'm doing in the code:

[Documentation for Array.filter -- MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

[Array.filter is better than $filter('filter') -- StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60495087/8796651)

[Documentation for String.includes -- MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)